# Which non-judged Olympic event has had the longest streak of different countries winning gold, ending in the most recent Olympics?

Tags: olympics, records

I want to know which non-judged Olympic event(s) is/are hardest for one country to dominate.

Which event has had the longest streak of totally different countries winning gold, with the streak including the most recent Olympics? That is, all the countries are different, not two alternating, so the streak doesn't include any country more than once, and includes either the 2018 or 2021 Games.

This could be either the Summer or Winter, not including Paralympics.

Comment: by @thefootsie's answer: would a "not held/not Olympic" break the streak? there are several disciplines which were in the early Olympics, then got replaced and reinstated afterwards (doesn't sound as a streak to me), also is ROC and Russia to be considered different countries?

Comment: @Vickel I would count ROC / Russia / Soviet Union as one country. I'd also say either East or West Germany would break a streak that includes Germany, but just having East and West without united Germany is OK.

Comment: @Vickel Not held is OK if it's one or two, but I would count it as breaking a streak if there's a period of decades without the event being held. To pick a number, let's say three not helds in a row are OK, but four isn't. Not helds don't count towards the length of the streak.

Comment: I think only ROC and Russia would make sense to count as the same country (and eventually E/W Germany, where this is the other way around, a merger). Soviet Union was split in I don't know how many counties, same goes for former Yugoslavia, anyway, after gong through all disciplines (except the ones which are obvious for certain counties supremacy) I found an 8 streak for men and a 7 for woman in the summer games. The Winter games produce way lower streak possibilities, since winter sports are traditionally limited to countries with low temperatures

Comment: Thanks for the info! I'll accept after 24 hrs unless someone finds a longer streak.

Comment: Streak of 11: Greco-Roman wrestling > Lightweight > Men. 
Streak of 8: Gymnastics > Horizontal bar > Men.
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_Greco-Roman_wrestling

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found - so far - a 8 streak for men and a 7 for woman in the Summer games. The Winter games produce way lower streak possibilities, since winter sports are traditionally limited to countries with low temperatures

top candidates at the moment (disciplines have referees, but not a judging system) are:

**summer**

- tennis, doubles, *men*: 8 (92-21); [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_tennis)
- sailing, one person dinghy, *woman*: 7 (96-21); [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_sailing_by_discipline)

**winter**

- ski alpine, downhill, *women*: 6 (98-18) [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_alpine_skiing)
- nordic, 10 km individual large hill, *men*: 5 (02-18) [source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_Nordic_combined)

please feel free to edit-in other disciplines matching at least the current top-streak, including the source

Answer (score 0):

For Summer Olympics the event that screams out for variability is a Cycling Road Race, lots of competitors from approx. 60 countries, one round, lots that can go wrong. It was the first event I looked at and having trawled through all sorts of other sports and disciplines, the [Men's individual road race](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cycling_at_the_Summer_Olympics#Men%27s_events_2) has the longest streak I can find.

- 2020 Ecuador
- 2016 Belgium
- 2012 Kazakhstan
- 2008 Spain
- 2004 *Italy*
- 2000 Germany
- 1996 Switzerland
- 1992 *Italy*

A slightly pedantic answer is [Men's Featherweight boxing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Olympic_medalists_in_boxing#Featherweight).

- 2020 ROC
- 2016 no comp
- 2012 no comp
- 2008 Ukraine
- 2004 Russia
- 2000 Kazakhstan
- 1996 Thailand
- 1992 Germany
- 1988 Italy
- 1984 USA
- 1980 East Germany
- 1976 Cuba
- 1972 *Soviet Union*
- 1968 Mexico
- 1964 *Soviet Union*

Comment: boxing has a judging system, so wouldn't qualify as answer? the men individual cycling road race would make up a streak of 7

Comment: Ye, good point.